# Find name of the radio button that is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

My page has about 25 radio button groups. When a radio button is selected in a group, I want to perform an action **Specific to that group**, and so need the **NAME** attrib of the radio group.

Comment: Need some more information for this one. Can you paste some markup and whatever relevant javascript you already have?

Comment: ASAP?!?!  I rushed here as soon as I could!  Where's the fire??

Comment: I only now saw your edit - this is **not** a good thing to do.  You have changed your edit in a way that **your question has in fact changed**.   This should **never** be done.  You got **two answers** and now they are not enough because they do not answer your recent edit.  Please revert your post and if needed in the future ask a **new** question.

Comment: @Lix Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. However, I think the post below answers the question. Also, in what way does the edit completely change the meaning of the answer?

Comment: Your question now talks about `css` - it doesn't have a `css` tag and didn't have one when you posted.  In any case your first question was to capture a group of elements and more specifically to extract the `name` attribute.  The answers posted below now are simply incomplete - they only solve half the problem.  That is what I mean.

Comment: @Lix Why I posted the way it is because I knew what and how to do the required after the NAME attrib is extracted. The problem was with the extraction of the attrib. Can you please post the complete solution for reference?

Comment: Absolutely not my friend. To answer your edit we would have to get more information - what markup you are using etc...  I'm sorry.  You should revert your question back to its [older version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9760411/revisions).  You can just click the "rollback" link.

Comment: @Lix Maybe now? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9761641/1277178 :) Ty in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take this HTML for example :

```
<div id="stackExchange">
  <input type="radio" name="sofu_group" value="Stack Overflow">
  <input type="radio" name="sofu_group" value="Meta Stack Overflow">
  <input type="radio" name="sofu_group" value="Server Fault">
  <input type="radio" name="sofu_group" value="Super User">
</div>
<!-- In no particular order - don't want to start a flame war ;) -->
```

If you wanted to deduce what group the clicked radio button belongs to you could use something like this :

```
// jQuery ver 1.7+
$("#stackExchange input:radio").on('click',function(){   
  var groupName = $(this).attr('name');
  var groupElements = $(this).parent().find(":radio[name='"+groupName+"']");
});
```

Lets see whats going on here :

- `$("#stackExchange input:radio")` - this selector will find us all of the input radio elements that are decendants of the `#stackExchange` element using the `:radio` selector. ([Link to docs](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)).
- `$(this).attr('name')` - here is where we extract the `name` attribute of the selected radio element. (In our example - this becomes `sofu_group`).
- `$(this).parent()` - In this case the variable `$(this)` refers to the radio element that was clicked - so we are selecting its parent - the `#stackExchange` element.
- `parent().find(":radio[name='"+groupName+"']")` - this line will find all of the radio buttons held within the element that have a name attribute set to 'sofu_group'.

<sub>In the example - the variable $(this) refers to the radio element that was clicked.</sub>

Comment: In the example, the name is sofu_group right? or is it stackExchange as said??

Comment: Thanks for that :) Yes - a small typo.  Fixed it now - the group name is indeed `sofu_group`.

Answer (score -2):

This might give you some hint

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked> Wine<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

call `document.getElementsByName("group1").items(0).<propertyname>or<function>`